# Voice recognition in .NET

Tags: .net, audio, artificial-intelligence, voice, voice-recognition

How to implement voice recognition in .NET?

I've got a bunch of `.mp3`s with computer generated voice of relatively high quality. In each `.mp3` the voice says some random text and then a sequence of 6-7 digits in English. I'd like to extract those digits as text.

Is it possible to implement such a thing in .NET?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a link to [the System.Speech.Recognition namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.aspx) that may help you out.

Comment: Yeah, this is the best way. Speech recognision/TTS has been part of the .NET BCL since 3.0.

Answer (score 2):

When working with Speech Recognition the best thing is to work in Windows Vista or Windows 7 cause they have Microsoft SAPI (Speech API) 5.3 (and will soon have 5.4) and that gives a big diference in performance comparing with SAPI 5.1 from Windows XP.

Now, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualc/cc482921.aspx) you have a video and source code (it's in c++ but you can pass it to another language) of an application that almost do what you want.

To recognize words in a better way, they make a grammar file with the words that they want to recognize. You can see that video and you will see that will be quite easy to make what you want.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Microsoft Speech to text Engines.. Its easy to use

Some samples [here](http://www.msagentring.org/setup.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Microsoft SAPI SDK: 
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=5e86ec97-40a7-453f-b0ee-6583171b4530&DisplayLang=en

 Check out the C# examples in SAPI SDK.